# How to fix "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" error in Socket.io + Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, express, sockets

I have a Socket.io application with Node.js as the backend server. I have hosted the client in [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) and the server in [Render](https://render.com/)

Server URL: slack-server.render.com
Client URL: slack.vercel.app

I have configured the CORS settings in the Socket instance in the backend.

server/index.js

```js
...

// Configurations and Constants
import { CLIENT_URL, PORT } from "./utils/config.js";

const app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    // Allow HTTP requests sent from client
    origin: CLIENT_URL,
  },
});
...
```

utils/config.js

```js
import "dotenv/config";

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const CLIENT_URL =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? process.env.CLIENT_URL
    : "http://localhost:5173";

...
```

client/src/socket.ts

```js
import { io, Socket } from "socket.io-client";

const URL =
  import.meta.env.MODE === "production"
    ? import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER_URL
    : "http://localhost:3000";

const createSocket = (namespace: string): Socket => {
  const socket: Socket = io(URL + "/" + namespace, {
    autoConnect: false, // Do not connect automatically
  });

  // For debugging purposes
  socket.onAny((event, ...args) => {
    // Print any event received by the client to the console
    console.log(event, args);
  });

  return socket;
};

const publicSocket = createSocket("public");
const privateSocket = createSocket("private");

export { Socket, publicSocket, privateSocket };
```

I have configured the environment variables in Render and Vercel settings.

When I try to access the client side at slack.vercel.app, I get the following error in the console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at
https://slack-server.onrender.com/socket.io/?name=johh&action=join&EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OpaAAdG.
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘https://slack.vercel.app/’)
```

How to fix this problem? Thanks.